# GRE Math Subject Practice Test Question 66: Which of the following are generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^×?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ be the ring of integers modulo 17, and let $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^×$ be the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ under multiplication. Which of the following are generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^×?$

I.$5$
II.$8$
III.$16$

(A) None

(B) I only

(C) II only

(D) III only

(E) I, II, and III

The answer is B. I wonder are there any other units besides 1 under multiplication? Or, what does this question mean and how to solve it?

Comment: Do you know what it means A) for an element to be a unit of a ring, B) for an element to generate a group? These may be details "lost in translation". Therefore they are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Definition of a unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory))
[Definition of a generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group)

Once you have correctly understood the question, you should be able to see with Lagrange's theorem that all elements $a$ of $\Bbb Z_{17}$ will satisfy $a^{16} = 1$, and moreover $a$ will be a generator if and only if $a^{8} \neq 1$.  For computational purposes, it is handy to note that $a^8 = [[a^2]^2]^2$ (notably, $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ is always cyclic).

Also notable: if you check each of these in order, you'll notice that $5^2 = 8$, which eliminates option II.